# Limiting density for sequence of points

Tags: measure-theory, probability-distributions

When $N\gg 1$, the sequence of points $\{x_1,x_2,...x_N\}$ given by $x_n=\frac{n}{N}$ can be described by the constant density $\rho(x)=1$, in the sense that the number of points between $a$ and $b$ equals $N\int_a^b\rho(x)dx$.

How can a sequence of points $\{x_1,x_2,...x_N\}$ be constructed, such that when $N\gg 1$ it can be described by a given density $\rho(x)$ (say a parabola for example, $\rho(x)=6x(1-x)$), in the sense that the number of points between $a$ and $b$ equals $N\int_a^b\rho(x)dx$?

In other words, I want a sequence of points that acumulates to form a continuum, but with non-constant density.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x_n=-\log(n/N)$ then the number of points up to $y$ is $Ne^{-y}$, which equals $N\int_0^y e^{-x}dx$. In this sense this sequence is described, for large $N$, by the probability density $\rho(x)=e^{-x}$.

If $x_n=(n/N)^2$ then the number of points up to $y$ is $N\sqrt{y}$, which equals $N\int_0^y \frac{dx}{2\sqrt{x}}$. In this sense this sequence is described, for large $N$, by the density $\rho(x)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$. But this is not a probability density.

In general, if $x_n=f(n/N)$ the number of points up to $y$ will be $Nf^{-1}(y)$, and the density will be $\rho(x)=\frac{d}{dx}f^{-1}(x)$. Finding $f(x)$ given $\rho(x)$ may be hard. The parabola case you mention, for example, is very messy.